# Allocate CSV columns in struct - allocation

Tags: c, csv, struct

I'm doing a program that read a CSV file and do some math operations with the column's elements. The file below is the one I'm working on, but, as you can see, he's pretty "hard" and only works if the file had a certain number of columns. Is there a way, in c, that I can allocate less columns that the ones I had declared in my struct? For example, if I have a file with only 2 columns, is there a way that I can allocate them in the first two elements of the struct without a segmentation problem?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    const int LINE_SIZE = 1024;

    typedef struct Person {
    int  age;
    double ga_ctg;
    double ga_b;
    char sex;
    double weight;
    double a1;
    double a5;
    double a7;

} Person;

char* getfield(char* line, int num)
{
char* tok;
for (tok = strtok(line, ";"); tok && *tok; tok = strtok(NULL, ";\n")){
    if (!--num)
        return tok;
}
return NULL;
}

int main(){
FILE* file = fopen("2.CSV", "r");
char line[LINE_SIZE];

Person* people;
int count = 0;

if (file == NULL) {
    perror("Error opening file");
    return -1;
}

char ch;
int column_Number = 0;
int line_Number = 0;

while((ch=fgetc(file))!=EOF) {
    if(ch==';'){
        column_Number++;
        line_Number++;
    }
    if (ch == '\n')
        break;
}
printf("Number of columns: %d \n\n", column_Number + 1); 


while (fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, file)){count++;} // counts the number of lines in file

// decreases count by one (since it will ignore first line of data)
count--;

if(count < 1) // no data
    return 0;

// allocate memory for the age array
people = (Person*)malloc(count * sizeof(Person));

if (people == NULL) {
    perror("error allocating people array");
    exit(0);
}

rewind(file); // rewinds file

fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, file); // reads first line (column names) and do nothing

count = 0; // reset count to use it as array index


while (fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, file)){

    
    char temp[LINE_SIZE];


    // Get every column of row as char*
    char* age = getfield(strcpy(temp, line),1);
    char* ga_ctg = getfield(strcpy(temp, line),2);
    char* ga_b = getfield(strcpy(temp, line), 3);
    char* sex = getfield(strcpy(temp, line),4);
    char* weight = getfield(strcpy(temp, line), 5);
    char* a1 = getfield(strcpy(temp, line), 6);
    char* a5 = getfield(strcpy(temp, line), 7);
    // stores converted values in the person array
    people[count].age = atoi(age);
    people[count].ga_ctg = atof(ga_ctg);
    people[count].ga_b = atof(ga_b);
    people[count].sex = sex[0];
    people[count].weight = atof(weight);
    people[count].a1 = atof(a1);
    people[count].a5 = atof(a5);
    
    // -------------------------------------------

    count++;
}
```

Comment: Lets say you can. How would your program "know" what data is in these columns? Also what would happen if the program is expecting some data that is "missing" for certain calculations? The answer to your question is generally "yes", but how exactly depends very much on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't know if I'll be able to explain, but I'll try: by the same way that the program is doing for these 8 columns. Only the first two members of the struct would have memory allocated and I would only use these two for the operations. The data would come from a different file, I forgot to mention that in my question

Comment: Your use of `getfield` is very ineffective. It's better to call `strtok` on `line` directly to get each consecutive field of the record.

Answer (score 0):

The C standard requires the members of a struct to be placed in memory in the same sequence that they are declared:

From C99 Standard, 6.7.2.1, paragraph 13

> Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.  This width could then be used to allocate memory for data associated with each person in the table using `malloc`.

Given this, you could use the member just beyond the last column to determine how much memory to allocate.  For example, if the last column entered were `weight`, then the required width could be determined using `(size_t)(&(((struct Person *)0)->a1))`.  There is also the `offsetof` macro in standard library `stddef.h` that performs the same function, which would be used `offsetof(struct Person, a1)` in this case (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_macro_offsetof.htm).

Defining the array would be a little bit trickier.  You could create an array of pointers to `People` (i.e. `People *`) then use the determined width and `malloc` to allocate memory for each.  Alternately, you could allocate an array of type `char` to be the width times the number of rows.  In this case, a member would be accessed by using the width times the person number to index the array, casting to type `(People *)` then referencing the member using `->`.

In this case, you would have to be extra careful not to try and write to elements beyond the last column.  Otherwise, the behavior is undefined and there could be a segmentation fault.  Also, this would require conditional blocks or a switch case to determine the required width based on the number of columns detected.

Comment: I though that was a way to struct the program for only use n elements of the struct (because there's no data to put put there), but it it more complicated than I thought. I should try allocate the elements in a multidimensional array, I think. Go to work, then. Thank you very much for your answer!